# Reduce applied to large inequality doesn't work

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I want to solve the next inequality :

```
Reduce[16 m5^2 + ma^2 + mp^2 - 
    Sqrt[(-16 m5^2 - ma^2 - mp^2)^2 - 4 (ma^2 mp^2 - 16 m5^2 q^2)] > 
   0 && m5 > 0  && q > 0 && ma > 0 && mp > 0, {q, m5}, Reals]
```

Where

```
ma = Sqrt[-2 (M^2 - 
     2 (3 k1 + k2) (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
        m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)))^2 - c + 2 m5^2)];
mp = Sqrt[
  2 b m ((Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
     m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)))^-1) ];
```

and

```
c = -44687.4; b = 161594.;k1 = 16.485; k2 = -13.1313; m = 5.5; M = 300;
```

But Mathematica solves it several hours and unfortunately without result. May you prompt where I mistake?

addition: if I write:

```
Reduce[m5 < (ma mp)/(4 q) && m5 > 0  && q > 0 && ma > 0 && 
  mp > 0, m5, Reals]
```

Then I found solution but answer will be very large one:

```
q > 0 && 0 < m5 < 
  Root[-2.27376*10^160 + (-6.7933*10^156 - 
        1.05104*10^151 q^2) #1^2 + (-8.26796*10^152 - 
        1.80431*10^147 q^2 + 
        2.59679*10^142 q^4) #1^4 + (-5.29216*10^148 - 
        1.15366*10^143 q^2 + 
        5.7805*10^138 q^4) #1^6 + (-1.88976*10^144 - 
        3.26407*10^138 q^2 + 
        5.12469*10^134 q^4) #1^8 + (-3.58288*10^139 - 
        3.45762*10^133 q^2 + 
        2.26515*10^130 q^4) #1^10 + (-2.82458*10^134 + 
        4.99895*10^125 q^4) #1^12 + 4.41285*10^120 q^4 #1^14 &, 2]
```

May it simplify?

Comment: What sort of result are you seeking?

Comment: @bbgodfrey For example form like q<10*m5

Answer (score 3):

**Rewrite to Accommodate Revised Question**

The solution provided in the revised question (designated here as `ff`) can be plotted by

```
ParametricPlot[{Log10[Evaluate[ff[[2, 3]]] /. q -> 10^logq], logq}, {logq, -.55, 9.53}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,  
    AxesLabel -> {"Log10[m5]", "Log10[q]"}, ImageSize -> 400, AxesOrigin -> {-5, -.55}]
```

[image]

This is, of course, equivalent to the simpler

```
LogLogPlot[ma mp/(4 m5), {m5, 10^-5, 10^8}, AxesLabel -> {"m5", "q"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but yours resalt is for ma=... and mp=... without  sqrt: ma = Sqrt[...] and Sqrt[...].  I add it after several hours as I placed question. It is my fault. You may ask me, what's the problem? Problem is that inequality in this case is:

Comment: 0 < m5 < 
  Root[-2.27376*10^160 + (-6.7933*10^156 - 
        1.05104*10^151 q^2) #1^2 + (-8.26796*10^152 - 
        1.80431*10^147 q^2 + 
        2.59679*10^142 q^4) #1^4 + (-5.29216*10^148 - 
        1.15366*10^143 q^2 + 
        5.7805*10^138 q^4) #1^6 + (-1.88976*10^144 - 
        3.26407*10^138 q^2 + 
        5.12469*10^134 q^4) #1^8 + (-3.58288*10^139 - 
        3.45762*10^133 q^2 + 
        2.26515*10^130 q^4) #1^10 + (-2.82458*10^134 + 
        4.99895*10^125 q^4) #1^12 + 4.41285*10^120 q^4 #1^14 &, 2]

Comment: This result can't be plotted

Answer (score 1):

It can be plotted. You can use PlotRegion to show the region.

In:

```
c = -44687.4; b = 161594.; k1 = 16.485; k2 = -13.1313; m = 5.5; M = \
300;
ma = Sqrt[-2 (M^2 - 
      2 (3 k1 + 
         k2) (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
          m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)))^2 - c + 2 m5^2)];
mp = Sqrt[
   2 b m ((Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)/(2 (k1 + k2))] + 
        m b/(2 (c + M^2 + 2 m5^2)))^-1)];

f = 16 m5^2 + ma^2 + mp^2 - 
   Sqrt[(-16 m5^2 - ma^2 - mp^2)^2 - 4 (ma^2 mp^2 - 16 m5^2 q^2)];
RegionPlot[f > 0, {m5, 0, 10000}, {q, 0, 1000}, Axes -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"m5", "q"}]
```

Out:
[image]